# Getting NullPointerException while setting SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to set the `SharedPrefences`in my `onPostExecute` method but I get `NullPointerException` in my error log. I've tried to put it `doInBackground()` but that blocks my result to be returned. So this is the code

**My Task class**

```
public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private final String mEmail;
    private final String mPassword;

    private  SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    private final String MyPREFERENCES = "session" ;

    String url = ****

    LoginTask(String email, String password) {
        mEmail = email;
        mPassword = password;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public String doInBackground(Void... params) {
       // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

        try {
            // Simulate network access.
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return "false";
        }

        ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", mEmail));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", mPassword));

        //Prepare the Post query

        try {
            HttpClient clientHttp = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = clientHttp.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = reader.readLine();
            sb.append(line + "\n");
            is.close();

            String result = sb.toString();

            System.out.println(result);


            return result;



        }catch (Exception e){

            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String res) {
        try {
             jObj = new JSONObject(res);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if (jObj.getString("code").equals("1")) {

                SharedPreferences.Editor e = sharedpreferences.edit();
                e.putString(MyPREFERENCES,"active");
                e.commit();

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), HomesActivity.class);

                //Lançer l'activité
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

            } else {
                //password.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
                //password.requestFocus();
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setTitle("Error !");
                builder.setMessage("The information entered is incorrect.\nPlease try again!")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        LoginTask = null;
        //showProgress(false);
    }
}
```

**My error Log :**

```
10-09 12:58:50.088    2878-2878/com.example.user.unchained E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.user.unchained, PID: 2878
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.user.unchained.EmailLoginActivity$LoginTask.onPostExecute(EmailLoginActivity.java:328)
        at com.example.user.unchained.EmailLoginActivity$LoginTask.onPostExecute(EmailLoginActivity.java:255)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You should use a debugger. A possible candidate would be `jObj.getString("code").equals("1")`, since you might invoke `equals` on a `null` `String`.

Comment: You need to post the code from where you are calling onPostExecute and not just onPostExecute method... I feel that the variable res in onPostExecute you are passing it as null.

Comment: @wrongAnswer I think the `onPostExecute` method is fine, as long as `res != null`. After all the stack traces starts there.

Comment: Just for information my code work very will until i've added the 3 lines of code contains the sharePreferences

Comment: @KANDROIDOS could be that your `sharedpreferences` variable is `null` then. Hence the possible `NullPointerException` when invoking `.edit()`...

Comment: `sharedpreferences` is null...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sharedpreferences` is `null`. You declare it here

```
private  SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
```

but you never initialize it (give it a value) before trying to use it here

```
SharedPreferences.Editor e = sharedpreferences.edit();
```

Before that line, you need something like

```
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPref", 0);
```

but for this you will need a `Context`. So, if this is a separate class then you will need to pass the `Context` of the `Activity` to the `AsyncTask` constructor.

So, you will need to make a class variable like `Context mContext;` then change your constructor to

```
LoginTask(String email, String password, Context c) {
    mEmail = email;
    mPassword = password;
    mContext = c;
}
```

Then when calling this task, pass the activity context along with the email and password with `this` or `ActivityName.this`, or something else depending on how/where it is called.

Now, when you initialize your `SharedPreference` object it will be

```
sharedpreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("myPref", 0);
```

Comment: it'w work for me, the first part of the solution but, why have you update the solution ?

Comment: I added more information in case it wasn't an inner-class of your `Activity`. If it was a separate class, then you would need to pass `Context` through the constructor.

Comment: Ok, thanks, it's an inner-class. PS: could you please make a up vote to leave the down vote thanks again !

Comment: You're welcome. And just an fyi...asking for votes on SE is highly frowned upon. And once you don't worry about rep, you will be much better off. The votes will come when they are warrranted

Comment: The problem is that the account is quickly closed  :/ thanks anyway

Comment: I only see one dv on your questions. Don't go deleting posts and try to answer some when you can and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Hi in your code i can't find the sharedpreferences object initialization.

```
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

or

```
sharedpreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

Then you will not get null pointer Exception.

Answer (score 1):

Your `sharedpreferences` is probably `null` when you invoke `edit()`.

There is no sign of initialization throughout the code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

you have to initialize sharedpreference  here sharedpreference is null. use SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Answer (score 1):

`sharedpreferences` is never initialized.

Maybe something like that :

```
LoginTask(Context context, String email, String password) {
    mEmail = email;
    mPassword = password;
    sharedpreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
}
```